# Another way to say "He brings trust-worthy feeling"

Tags: expressions

The context is for a comment of an employment to the employee. *"He brings trust-worthy feeling"*. It's not just *"He's trust-worthy"* but here, the man has gone through many difficult tasks and he always managed to succeed every time. It's like a person you can trust and rely on. So is there another way of expression ?

Comment: "He is dependable", "he is someone you can depend on" might work for you.

Comment: Please do not ask for help writing (or proofreading). They are out of scope and your question may be removed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research. [(more¹)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) [(more²)](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) [(more³)](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/3226/14073)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common phrase in AmE is

> *He **inspires** trust*.

For example, the following is a quote from a *Forbes* article entitled [*You Can't Be a Great Leader Without Trust. Here's How You Build It.*](http://www.forbes.com/sites/forbesleadershipforum/2012/10/24/you-cant-be-a-great-leader-without-trust-heres-how-you-build-it/#2b4abc87a48b)

> Leaders who **inspire trust** garner better output, morale, retention, innovation, loyalty, and revenue, while mistrust fosters skepticism, frustration, low productivity, lost sales, and turnover.

This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inspire%20trust%2C%20inspires%20trust&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinspire%20trust%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinspires%20trust%3B%2Cc0) shows the frequency of the use of the phrase.

Comment: Please consider adding support for this answer, ideally with citations.

Answer (score 4):

> It's like a person you can trust and rely on.

This person is [**reliable**](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20reliable):

> consistently good in quality or performance; able to be trusted.
>
> *"a reliable source of information"*
>
> **synonyms:**
>
> - dependable, good, well founded, authentic, valid, genuine, sound, true
>
>   - *"reliable evidence"*
> - trustworthy, dependable, good, true, faithful, devoted, steadfast, staunch, constant, loyal, trusty, dedicated, unfailing; truthful,
>     honest
>
>   - *"a reliable friend"*
> - dependable, safe, fail-safe
>
>   - *"reliable brakes"*
> - reputable, dependable, trustworthy, honest, responsible, established, proven
>
>   - *"a reliable company"*
> - a person or thing with trustworthy qualities.
>
>   - *"the supporting cast includes old reliables like Mitchell"*

Answer (score 1):

*"He is **somebody to lean on"***

Lean on somebody or something — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lean+on)

> *Figuratively* 1. To depend on someone or something.
>
> *"The children leaned on each other for help and comfort."*
> *"Verplank leaned on his experience as a waiter to figure out how to behave when he met the prince."*